# The initial value problem $|\frac{dy}{dx}|+2|y|=0$, $\,$ $y(0)=1$ has no solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The initial value problem $|\frac{dy}{dx}|+2|y|=0$, $\,$ $y(0)=1$  has no solution.

How to do this?

Should I find the find the solutions of  $\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=0$ $\,$ and$\,$  $\frac{dy}{dx}-2y=0$ $\,$ these O.D.E's?

Any hint will also help me.

Comment: What can you conclude from $$|y'| = -2|y|$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $x=0$, we must have $\big\lvert\frac{dy}{dx}\big\rvert_{x=0}=-2|y(0)|=-2$, which is obviously impossible. (Basically, because you want the sum of two absolute values to be $0$, it follows that they both must always be $0$.)